# PHP $_POST don't save on mysql by a html form

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to save some data on mysql but it doesn't save.

Note: mysql database works fine under direct console code.

Heres my HTML code:

```
<form method="post" action="prueba1.php" >
    Nombre: <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" /></br>
    Email: <input type="text" name="email" id="email" /></br>
    Comentarios: <input type="text" name="comentarios" id="comentarios" / ></br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Registrar" />
    </form>
```

Heres my PHP code:

```
if(!empty($_POST))
    {
        try
            {
                $nombre = $_POST ['nombre'];
                $email = $_POST ['correo'];
                $comentarios = $_POST ['comentarios'];
                $sql_insert = "
                INSERT INTO usuario (nombre, correo, comentarios)
                VALUES (?,?,?) ";
                $stmt = $con->prepare($sql_insert);
                $stmt->bindValue(1, $nombre);
                $stmt->bindValue(2, $email);
                $stmt->bindValue(3, $comentarios);
                $stmt->execute();
                echo "<h3>Tu comentario se a registrado con éxito</h3>";
                            }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
                echo "<h3>No se pudo registrar tu comentario</h3>";
                die(var_dump($e));
        }
```

Note: When I push button with value "Registrar" tells me that it save has been success. But there's not exist on the database.

Any help will be appreciated.

Best regards.

Comment: You should check the return values of your various `prepare`, `bind` and `execute` calls for errors and retrieve the error message if you find some. Without that you have no idea what's happening.

Comment: Also looks like you are missing a ending "}" for the if statement -

Comment: Yes @MikeW is right in saying that you need to check the return value before confirming that the operation was successful. Also, if possible try to execute the query directly in an sql client first to check that the syntax is proper and you are not missing any field. My best guess is that you might have a primary key id in table which is not set to auto increment. Can you provide your table design if possible?

Answer (score 1):

**Clarification**, Is it the right way to use

```
 $stmt->bindValue(1, $nombre);
 $stmt->bindValue(2, $email);
 $stmt->bindValue(3, $comentarios);
```

Because I have only used [bind_param](http://www.pontikis.net/blog/how-to-use-php-improved-mysqli-extension-and-why-you-should)

```
$stmt->bind_param('is',$value1,$value2); // where i is integer and s is string
```

try using

```
 $stmt->bind_param('sss',$nombre,$email,$comentarios); // hope all three are strings
```

And check for entry in database, Sorry if I am wrong...

Answer (score 0):

i think your Insert query is wrong

```
INSERT INTO usuario (nombre, correo, comentarios) VALUES (?,?,?) ";
```

your values contains '?', I think it should be this way

```
 INSERT INTO usuario (nombre, correo, comentarios) VALUES ('$nombre','$correo','$comentarios') ";
```

Comment: OP is using (or attempting to use) prepared statements. Your suggestion bypasses that and opens him to for SQL Injection attacks